# Compute X and Y differences for all couple of points, by group, keeping initial columns

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations, distance, difference

I have a data.frame with coordinates and group information like this:

```
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x=round(runif(6,1,100)), y=round(runif(6,100,200)), group=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A"))
```

I want to create a "differences" data.frame, from all combinations of 2 points and compute the difference in X coordinates in first column, in Y in the second column. I came up with this code that is absolutely not efficient imo:

```
comp.diff = function(H, data) {(data[H[1], 1:2]- data[H[2], 1:2])}
comb = df %>% nrow %>% combn(2) %>% {cbind(., .[2:1, ])} # make all combinations in both ways
apply(comb, 2, comp.diff, data = df) %>% do.call('rbind.data.frame', .)
```

But I can't achieve two more things:

- I want to compute (or keep) only the differences of couples of point taken from the **same group**
- I would like to keep, for each row in the output matrix, the information about the initial x, the initial y, and the id of the group concerned

How can I achieve this in an *efficient way* (obviously, number of combinations grow fast with N...)
Thanks

Structure of expected output (extract):

```
####   delta.x delta.y old.x old.y group
#### 1     -11      28    27   166     A
#### 5     -63      76    27   118     A
#### ...
```

Comment: Is `f` supposed to be `comp.diff`?

Comment: @Jimbou the last line of `df` belongs to group A as well

Comment: and how it is calculated? `df$x` in `group == "A"` concists of `c(58, 27, 38)`. So how you get a result of `-63`. The second question is which of the two values you want to keep. The first or the second?

Comment: @Jimbou maybe run the initial df again? I have c(27, 38, 90) for x in group A. Second question (good one:-) ) i guess it doesn't matter because in the `comb` definition i compute the differences in both ways (xi-xj) AND (xj-xi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
# calculate the combinations per group
combs <- df %>% 
  split(.$group) %>% 
  map(~combn(1:nrow(.),2)) 

# the calcualtion
df %>% 
  mutate(index=1:n()) %>% 
  split(.$group) %>% 
  map2(combs, ., ~data.frame(t(apply(.x, 2, function(i) 
    cbind(paste(.y$index[i], collapse = "-"),
          .y$x[i[1]],.y$x[i[2]],.y$y[i[1]],.y$y[i[2]],
          -diff(.y$x[i]), -diff(.y$y[i])))),stringsAsFactors = F)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "group") %>% 
  dplyr::select(1, index_diff=2, 
                x1_old=3, x2_old=4,
                y1_old=5, y2_old=6,
                diff_x=7,diff_y=8)
```

## Edit

and alltogether in one pipe including transformation to integers

```
df %>% 
  mutate(index=1:n()) %>% 
  split(.$group) %>% 
  map(~data.frame(t(apply(combn(1:nrow(.),2), 2, function(i) 
    cbind(paste(.$index[i], collapse = "-"),
          .$x[i[1]],.$x[i[2]],.$y[i[1]],.$y[i[2]],
          -diff(.$x[i]), -diff(.$y[i])))),stringsAsFactors = F)) %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "group") %>% 
  dplyr::select(1, index_diff=2, 
                x1_old=3, x2_old=4,
                y1_old=5, y2_old=6,
                diff_x=7,diff_y=8) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(x1_old:diff_y), as.numeric) %>% 
  as.tibble()
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  group index_diff x1_old x2_old y1_old y2_old diff_x diff_y
  <chr> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A     1-2            27     38    194    166    -11     28
2 A     1-6            27     90    194    118    -63     76
3 A     2-6            38     90    166    118    -52     48
4 B     3-4            58     91    163    106    -33     57
5 B     3-5            58     21    163    121     37     42
6 B     4-5            91     21    106    121     70    -15
```

Comment: With the sample data? No, it is running here. Check `str(df)` and compare the output to your sample data.

Comment: ok, it work well indeed the results seem correct, and in addition much faster than my code. Thanks, that really help me!

Comment: there it just another detail (but easy to fix) the output columns are in character format